# Card CVV Number Validation Randomly between 2 digits only in java

Tags: java, validation, random, numbers, cvv8

How to validate the customer CVV number only 2 digits randomly between 3 actual number? 
Eg: CVV number is 123, i ask customer to provide only 2 digits. it can be 1st and 2nd digit, or 1st and 3rd etc.

I should use some random number generation logic in java. Please suggest me options i can use. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just generate two random numbers between 1 and 3, and pick the corresponding digits?

Answer (score 0):

Have the computer generate a random between 1 and 3 and then take that number out after its been used.

```
int[] CVV = {1,2,3};
int number1 = (int)(Math.random()*CVV.length);
int number2 = (int)(Math.random()*CVV.length);
while(number1 == number2){
     number2 = (int)(Math.random()*CVV.length);
}
```